# django replace old image uploaded by ImageField

Tags: python, django

How I can replace one image uploaded by an ImageField (in my models) with the new one selected by the same ImageField?

And, can I delete all images uploaded by an ImageField when I delete the model object (bulk delete)?

Answer (score 2):

After hours of searching I found this code.
It worked for me in Django 3

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            this = Image.objects.get(id=self.id)
            if this.image != self.image:
                this.image.delete(save=False)
        except:
            pass  # when new photo then we do nothing, normal case
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

This might get tricky, 
And a lot of times depends on what are your constraints. 
1. Write your own save method for the model and then delete the old image a and replace with a new one. 
     os.popen("rm %s" % str(info.photo.path))

1. Write a cron job to purge all the unreferenced files. But then again if disk space is a issue, you might want to do the 1st one, that will get you some delay in page load.

Comment: If I prefer 1st solution, but there is the case when I update the object without add a new image. How can I check if a new image has been submitted??

Comment: So when your updating a object you check if it has a image to be saved, if so you save it. 
and the case you mentioned, when you don't have a image to be replaced, you just save the other fields.

Comment: Ok, but if an image exist, how can I check if the user has selected a new image in the form or not??

Comment: this = Photo.objects.get(id=self.id)
            if this.image != self.image:
else the normal use case